# Choosing overloaded void* operator for inputstream

Tags: c++

How is the inputstream's overloaded void* cast operator chosen when the compiler sees something like

```
int a;
while(cin >> a) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

> 1) Returns a null pointer if fail() returns true, otherwise returns a
>   non-null pointer. **This pointer is implicitly convertible to bool and
>   may be used in boolean contexts.**

n3376 4.12/1

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, **pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool.** A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to false; any other value is converted to true.

Comment: Is it like the "cin >> a" is treated under boolean context and operation void* is picked up the compiler?

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that 1) in C++11 and later, the conversion operator is `operator bool`, not `operator void*`, and 2) the _only_ legal use of the `void*` returned in earlier versions is to be converted to `bool`.